# MYSQL Query to fetch the list of check-in and check out for each user

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table where the sensor will constantly insert data to the db with flag = 1 when a user is in the zone, and when he moves out of the zone, until it can read the card, it will send the data with flag = 0. how to fetch the pair of check-in and check-out for each user. The table structure is as below[image]

```
Minor|Check-in|created  
=====|========|=======  
3002 |0       |2017-09-29 18:07:38  
3002 |0       |2017-09-29 18:07:46  
3002 |0       |2017-09-29 18:07:52  
3002 |1       |2017-09-29 18:08:22  
3002 |1       |2017-09-29 18:08:44  
3002 |1       |2017-09-29 18:08:52  
3002 |1       |2017-09-29 18:09:04  
3002 |0       |2017-09-29 18:09:48  
3002 |0       |2017-09-29 18:12:14  
3002 |0       |2017-09-29 18:14:44  
3002 |1       |2017-09-29 18:21:32  
3002 |0       |2017-09-29 18:21:40  
3002 |0       |2017-09-29 18:21:48  
3002 |0       |2017-09-29 18:22:14
```

Expected output is:

```
Minor |status |time 
3022  | 1     |2017-09-29 18:08:22  
3022  | 0     |2017-09-29 18:09:48  
3022  | 1     |2017-09-29 18:21:32   
3022  | 0     |2017-09-29 18:21:40
```

Checkin checkout can be in 2 rows as above or in a single row as below,

```
Minor   |      check-in     | Check-out      
========|===================|===================  
3022    |2017-09-29 18:08:22|2017-09-29 18:09:48  
3022    |2017-09-29 18:21:32|2017-09-29 18:21:40
```

We need to fetch the check-in and check-out for each minor. Logic would be need to take one set of check-in and check-out for a minor, so the check-in will be the first created time which has check-in flag as 1, and check-out will be the created time for the minor whose check-in flag is 0.

Note:
Minor can have a check-in alone, and no checkout.

Kindly advice
Thanks

Comment: Now, I'm getting the resultset and iterating it in java by getting the first check-in flag as 1 for each minor and ignoring all 1's for that minor and taking first check-in as 0. this is considered as a pair of check-in and check-out. Is there a way in query itself we can get the check-in and chek-out of each minor

Comment: Kindly share sample data and desired output in formatted text (not images)

Comment: As far as i can see, there is no check-out for minor `32001` and no check-in for `4864`.

Comment: Hi @Zarruq . Thanks for the comments, and sorry for not being clear. Few minors will not have check-in at all, if they didnt come into the zone. Since each reader has a defined radius, only if the distance is within the radius it will send a check-in flag, otherwise it will send a checkout flag, likewise, few minors will have check-outs if they remain in the zone itself.

Comment: @Zarruq, I've edited my question, Kindly provide your thoughts on the same.

Comment: It seems you merely want to keep all records where the previous record has another status. That would be very easy with the standard SQL function `LAG`. MySQL, however, lacks this function, so look up on how to emulate `LAG` in MySQL. You will have to use a variable, I guess.

Comment: Where is Every minute?

Comment: @Strawberry, the BLE will be sending data for every minute, Internally we have a business logic, where we maintain a static Multimap, which will have a key value data for each minor, we maintain 5 values in the multimap, and calculate accuracy by taking average of the distance and then push it into the DB. so in DB we cannot see every minute.

Comment: Consider amending the question accordingly.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner yes, Checking on that

Comment: This just isn't good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E.g.:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(minor INT NOT NULL
,checkin TINYINT NOT NULL
,created  DATETIME NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(minor,created)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(3002,0,'2017-09-29 18:07:38'),
(3002,0,'2017-09-29 18:07:46'),
(3002,0,'2017-09-29 18:07:52'),
(3002,1,'2017-09-29 18:08:22'),
(3002,1,'2017-09-29 18:08:44'),
(3002,1,'2017-09-29 18:08:52'),
(3002,1,'2017-09-29 18:09:04'),
(3002,0,'2017-09-29 18:09:48'),
(3002,0,'2017-09-29 18:12:14'),
(3002,0,'2017-09-29 18:14:44'),
(3002,1,'2017-09-29 18:21:32'),
(3002,0,'2017-09-29 18:21:40'),
(3002,0,'2017-09-29 18:21:48'),
(3002,0,'2017-09-29 18:22:14');

SELECT checkin
     , created 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.*
            , CASE WHEN @prev <> checkin THEN @stamp:=created END stamp
            , @prev:=checkin prev 
         FROM my_table x
            , (SELECT @prev:=null,@created:=null) vars 
        ORDER 
           BY created
     ) a
 WHERE stamp IS NOT NULL
 ORDER 
    BY created;

+---------+---------------------+
| checkin | created             |
+---------+---------------------+
|       1 | 2017-09-29 18:08:22 |
|       0 | 2017-09-29 18:09:48 |
|       1 | 2017-09-29 18:21:32 |
|       0 | 2017-09-29 18:21:40 |
+---------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this one will still return all duplicate fields also. it does not return the pair of check-in and check-outs. Let me try on this to modify as required. Thank you

Comment: Kindly refer the output format in the question. this query will not generate the expected result.

Comment: your answer works perfectly if the minor has check-in and check-out. if there is no checkout for one minor, then for the next minor, it does not shows the check-in , it shows the checkout alone. Let me try to resolve it.

Comment: works fine if there exists a check out for every check in.

Comment: Thanks. It is not a different question, same question with different scenario. edited the question.